# Is it legal to use $schema in subschemas?

Tags: jsonschema

The JSON Schema specification says this [[1]](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-bhutton-json-schema-01#section-8.1.1):

```
The "$schema" keyword SHOULD be used in the document root schema object, and MAY be used in the root schema objects of embedded schema resources. It MUST NOT appear in non-resource root schema objects.
```

I am unclear what that means. What is a "non-resource root schema object"?

Can subschemas contain the `$schema` keyword, *e.g.,*

```
{
   "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
   "type": "array",
   "maxItems": 3,
   "unevaluatedItems": {
       "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
       "type": "integer"
   }
}
```

I pasted that schema into the [online Hyperjump validator](https://json-schema.hyperjump.io/) and the validator didn't flag an error, so I am assuming that it is okay (although not recommended) to put `$schema` in subschemas. Yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$schema` in a subschema that's not a schema resource (identified by `$id`) is actually forbidden by the 2020-12 spec.

> It MUST NOT appear in non-resource root schema objects. ([link](https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-core.html#section-8.1.1-4))

A subschema becomes a resource root if it contains an `$id` that gives the subschema a new base URI.

For your case, Hyperjump is likely ignoring the keyword because either `$id` is missing or the `$schema` value is unchanged from the parent schema.

For completeness, my validator, https://json-everything.net/json-schema, also doesn't flag it.  I'll discuss with the team to see if this should be considered a bug.

Comment: I can confirm that `@hyperjump/json-schema` will ignore `$schema` when used in places where it's meaningless.